# Unclear how to include PyMySQL with RSA in requirements.txt or setup

Tags: rsa, setup.py, pymysql, requirements.txt

Thanks for your work, working well..

I am able to install the rsa version with `python3 -m pip install PyMySQL[rsa]`, but:

1. I don’t know how to specify rsa in a requirements.txt file
2. More seriously, I cannot build the setup.py file (I am the author of
   [API Logic Server](https://apilogicserver.github.io/Docs/))

My setup contains:

```
    "PyMySQL==1.0.3[rsa]", 
    # "PyMySQL==1.0.3+rsa”,  or maybe this?
```

The setup runs, but the result fails to pip install with both variants:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyMySQL==1.0.3[rsa] (from apilogicserver) (from versions: 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4.dev1, 0.6.4, 0.6.6, 0.6.7, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.4, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.7.7, 0.7.8, 0.7.9, 0.7.10, 0.7.11, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3rc1, 1.0.3, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyMySQL==1.0.3[rsa]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.

I read this: `pip install PyMySQL[rsa]`, and incorrectly inferred that it was a special PyMSQL package.

It is not.  It's a shorthand for ***2 installs:*** `PyMySQL` and `rsa`.

The syntax above works fine with `pip`.  If you want to create a `requirements.txt` file, or a `setup.py` file, simply do 2 installs.